# Como as expressões lambdas conseguem tratar variáveis da stack?

Tags: c#, .net, expressões-lambda, gerenciamento-de-memória, stack

Estou aprendendo C# e to lendo sobre expressões lambdas. A pergunta que ficou é: como isso funciona e por que funciona?

```
    public delegate void Test();

    public void Foobar(ref Test del)
    {
        int var = 10;
        del = () => Console.WriteLine(var);
    }
```

Chamada:

```
Test bar;

Foobar(ref bar);
bar();
```

Pelo o que eu li, a expressão lambda não abriga valores e sim referências. Mas se a variável **var** é uma variável criada na stack e não na heap, como isso consegue imprimir 10, visto que a variável 'var' foi desalocada no final do método **Foobar**? Ou eu entendi o conceito errado? Me expliquem por favor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simples, não colocando na *stack*.

A infraestrutura de delegados que é o mecanismo básico da *lambda* permite o uso do que se chama clausura (*closure*). Ou seja, ele prende um estado dentro da função e leva consigo para onde for. Não é que o dado precise se transforma em referência, mas precisará ter alguma referência para algum objeto no *heap* onde tem o dado.

Então o compilador gera um código interno que trata o que normalmente estaria na *stack* e coloca no *heap* que é um local onde os dados tem tempo de vida indeterminado.

No caso o tempo de vida deste dado, acessado por uma variável, está vinculado ao tempo de vida da função anônima. No caso do .NET sua destruição ocorrerá em algum momento após uma coleta de lixo for disparada na geração em que ela está.

Então enquanto a *lambda* existir a variável existirá, não será liberada.

Note que pode haver algum efeito inesperado, principalmente em laços, já que o valor local pode estar dissociado do valor da *lambda*. Um exemplo comum é um laço ir até 10 e mandar executar a *lambda* depois, mesmo que a pessoa não perceba que é depois, e o valor será sempre 10 e não de 1 à 10 como a pessoa esperaria. A *lambda* é um mecanismo usado para *lazy evaluation*.

## Como é internamente

Não poderia citar ninguém menos que o cara que escreveu o código do compilador que faz isto, *ladies and gentlemen*: [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42169237/221800).

```
class C1 {
    Func<int, int, int> M() => (x, y) => x + y;
}
```

Se transforma em:

```
class C1 {
    static Func<int, int, int> theFunction;
    static int Anonymous(int x, int y) => x + y;
    Func<int, int, int> M() {
        if (C1.theFunction == null) C1.theFunction = C1.Anonymous;
        return C1.theFunction;
    }
}
```

[Código real no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMDcCwAoEBmK0BsUBM6DsEA3khKVGjFiACzoAcAFAJRElkC+SniSIuAwtFaIyUAKwAeAJYA7AC4AaCLMXL5APggBZZhAC8mhgA8lATxYGIRiAGoIphInZA==).

```
class C2 {
    static int counter = 0;
    int x = counter++;
    Func<int, int> M() => y => this.x + y;
}
```

Se transforma em:

```
class C2 {
    static int counter = 0;
    int x = counter++;
    int Anonymous(int y) => this.x + y;
    Func<int, int> M() => this.Anonymous;
}
```

[Código real no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMDcCwAoEBmK0BsUBM6DsEA3khKVGjFiACzoAcAFAJRElkC+SniSIuAwrmKIy6LAEsAdgBcIAYwD2AVxkBTAE4QAvBDAIRZKbIAe2+crXqA1Ff2iQAVgA8RgDQQjAPggBZZtu8ATwCIaQALcQBnADpTKwhA/XYgA).

```
class C3 {
    static int counter = 0;
    int x = counter++;
    Func<int> M(int y) => () => x + y;
}
```

Se transforma em:

```
class C3 {
    class Locals {
      public C3 __this;
      public int __y;
      public int Anonymous() => this.__this.x + this.__y;
    }
    Func<int> M(int y) {
      var locals = new Locals();
      locals.__this = this;
      locals.__y = y;
      return locals.Anonymous;
    }
}
```

[Código real no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMDcCwAoEBmK0BsUBM6DsEA3khKVGjFiACzoAcAFAJRElkC+SniSIuAwmmKIy6LAEsAdgBcIAYwD2AVxkBTAE4QAvBDAIRZKbIAe2+crXqA1Ff2iQAVgA8RgHwQAsgyMQAniy13Zm13Uys/fXYgA).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Lambda/Lambdas.cs).