# Como funcionam closures em Swift?

Tags: swift, closures

Talvez esse seja um dos conceitos mais difíceis de entender para quem está começando na linguagem. Já vi algumas definições mas até agora não consegui entender.

Alguém poderia dar uma explicação com exemplos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade já explicamos isso em diversas postagens sobre a *closure* em sí e a função anônima que é conceito relacionado e importante:

- [Qual a diferença entre as funções var name = function() e function name()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/101)
- [Como funcionam Closures em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre uma expressão lambda, um closure e um delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101)
- [O que são lambda expressions? E qual a sacada em usá-las?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2822/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre uma expressão lambda, um closure e um delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101)
- [Qual a finalidade de declarar uma função dentro de uma função?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252596/101)

Siga os *links* nas postagens acima para entender todo o conceito (eu percebo que muitas pessoas tem dificuldade para entender porque elas não querem aprender todos os detalhes).

Então vou resumir aqui porque quase tudo já foi dito em detalhes antes.

## Função anônima

O termo correto para o mecanismo básico.

A função anônima é a função sem nome, é aquela função que é associada a um objeto através de uma variável local, incluindo o parâmetro ou de um objeto (instância ou do tipo). Assim você pode ir transportando a função para todos os cantos da aplicação como se a função fosse um dado, um valor qualquer.

Isso dá uma flexibilidade muito grande e usando a criatividade pode tornar-se um mecanismo poderoso de personalização de objetos e métodos para executar algum algoritmo que será definido em outro lugar. Então você pode escrever um código universal em certo ponto da aplicação, mas que uma parte da execução será definida em outro ponto. Essa parte será conhecida através de uma função anônima, geralmente escrita com uma sintaxe de *lambda*.

Swift permite isso porque a função é de [primeira classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227485/101).

A função anônima é só uma função normal que tem uma indireção a mais através de um ponteiro então a função funciona como um objeto, ela é tratada como se fosse um dado.

Curiosamente parece que Swift trata a função anônima normal como *closure* mesmo que não faça a captura. Pode ser que porque internamente ela mantenha um mecanismo de captura mesmo que a captura não seja feita. Estritamente o termo está errado nesse contexto, Swift tem umas reinvenções próprias, que não é exatamente ruim, mas parece muito cara da Apple. A verdadeira clausura só ocorre no exemplo que colocarei abaixo, nos outros exemplos nada é enclausurado mesmo que a documentação diga isso.

Não sei bem se o AP entende o que é esse mecanismo, ele em si não é tão complicado assim.

## *Closure*

Acontece que no momento que você define uma função anônima pode ser que use um valor que está contido em uma variável da função onde a função anônima está sendo escrita. Nós falamos que a função anônima captura esse valor. Então se você passar essa função para outro lugar (e só faz sentido ter uma função anônima se fizer isso) o valor que tinha naquela variável capturada vai junto com a função (não vou entrar no detalhe de implementação de como é feito isso, mas há implicações importantes).

Obviamente que só em alguns casos isso é necessário, depende do código que está escrevendo dentro da função. Se não usar alguma variável que estava no [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) da função onde a função anônima foi definida então não há uma clausura ocorrendo.

Estou falando em definir uma função dentro de outra que é o mais comum, mas poderia definir em um campo também, nesse caso o objeto capturado sempre será o `self`.

Quando a função anônima for usada nela em algum momento a variável é usada no algoritmo e o valor que a variável está valendo será usado.

Uma das coisas que acho que não é simples entender é sobre essa variável continuar existindo mesmo depois que você não está na mais na função onde ela existia. De fato a captura da variável irá enclausurar a variável dentro da função anônima, então o tempo de vida daquela variável é estendida e fica igual ao tempo de vida da função anônima.

A variável que provavelmente estaria na [*stack* passa para o *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) para manter o tempo de vida necessário. Como no *heap* tudo é armazenado por referência então geralmente qualquer mudança na variável feita em qualquer lugar acontecerá ali no *heap* e isso pode trazer surpresas que não vou falar aqui, mas [já tem respostas sobre](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/404127/101) ([outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170393/101)). [Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/306440/101).

## Exemplo

Então vamos a exemplo para demonstrar isso (vou pegar da [documentação](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)).

```
func makeIncrementer(forIncrement amount: Int) -> () -> Int {
    var runningTotal = 0
    func incrementer() -> Int {
        runningTotal += amount
        return runningTotal
    }
    return incrementer
}
let incrementBySeven = makeIncrementer(forIncrement: 7)
print(incrementBySeven())
print(incrementBySeven())
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/i4kpY2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/clkoqden-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Swift/Closure.swift).

Vamos entender o que acontece aí.

`makeIncrementer()` é uma função normal. A responsabilidade dela é criar uma função anônima para ser usada em outro local. Podemos ver que existe um parâmetro com um valor numérico.

Dentro dela existe uma variável chamada `runningTotal`. Ela é importante porque será capturada.

Em seguida definimos a função anônima chamada `incrementer`. Note que ela é uma variável como outra qualquer dentro de `makeIncrementer()`, tanto que a última linha da função há um `return incrementer`, portanto está retornando o objeto dessa variável, que é uma função, que tem capacidade de executar algo e capturar variáveis locais.

Dentro da função anônima uma conta é feita usando a variável local `runningTotal` e a variável `amount` que é um parâmetro. Ambas são capturadas pela função anônima. Então elas terão tempo de vida ampliado e essas variáveis existirão enquanto a função anônima ali definida continue existindo. Portanto poderá acessar seus valores por todo esse tempo.

Em seguida vemos um código normal que chama a `makeIncrementer` passando como argumento 7, então a variável `incrementBySeven` terá o objeto que `makeIncrementer` retornar. Sabemos que ela está retornando uma função anônima que tem duas variáveis capturadas.

Depois mandamos executar a função `incrementBySeven`. Sim, essa variável é uma função agora porque o objeto dela é uma função, podemos chamá-la. E o código é executado.

Como o código está sendo executado a primeira vez o valor de `runningTotal` está valendo 0, como sabemos olhando o código. E ele pegará esse valor e somar como o argumento que usamos, então 7. O retorno é o resultado dessa soma, por isso imprime 7.

Agora mandamos executar exatamente a mesma coisa. Como agora é a segunda vez que executa a variável `runningTotal` não vale 0, ela está valendo 7. Lembre-se que a variável ainda está viva dentro da função anônima que ainda existe. Então o valor de `runningTotal` agora é 7, e como mais uma soma de 7 o resultado será 14.

Pode chamar outras vezes e sempre será assim. Só voltaremos começar de 0 quando criarmos outro objeto com essa função anônima, porque aí começa tudo do 0. Isso só é possível porque o tempo de vida da variável passou ser global.

## Conclusão

A ideia da função anônima sem a clausura na verdade é bem mais simples até porque você vê a parametrização e só tem um conceito. Só para deixar um exemplo da documentação:

```
reversedNames = names.sorted(by: { (s1: String, s2: String) -> Bool in
    return s1 > s2
})
```

Aí você tem uma função sendo criada que será passada para a função `sorted()` que fará a classificação de dados e em dado momento usará sua função para estabelecer a ordem. Sua função será executada lá dentro em cada passo que precisa decidir se algo está na ordem ou precisa trocar posição.

Swift tem um monte de detalhe e variações de uso do mecanismo, mas aí vira um capítulo de um livro para falar de tudo, teria que fazer perguntas mais específicas.